# X509 Certificate does not display expiration date correctly. Is there a special format for the timestamp?

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, x509certificate, angular2-services

I'm having an issue where `X509` certificate expiration timestamp logged from the console does not match it's actual timestamp from KeyStore explorer.

It is not formatting correctly with the Angular2+ built-in `formatDate()` function; an error is thrown. The timestamp is valid if the certificate is opened via KeyStore Explorer. Due to that, I think I have to program a custom date formatter myself.

X509 logged-from-console timestamp:

[X509 logged-from-console timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9R3W.png)

X509 KeystoreExplorer timestamp:

[X509 KeystoreExplorer timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opFqq.png)

How do you make sense of the day and time (12-347 vs 12/13; T19:08 vs 11:08AM)? Is there some special convention for X509 certificate times?

Comment: Can you share some code of the "Angular2+ Date constructor" and the error that is thrown?

Comment: My apologies, I miss spoke. I actually use the built-in formatDate() function. The error that is thrown is `Error: Unable to convert "2029-12-347T19:08:55.055+0000" into a date
    at toDate `

Comment: Are you making an API call to get the `timestamp` into your angular app? Check what the `timestamp` being return is.

Comment: The certificate is created in Java with the expiration date as  `Thu Dec 13 11:08:55 PST 2029` and sent to the angular app. On the app, it is passed in as a `Date` object. I take it the issue may be how angular creates a Date object vs Java's version.

Comment: I think that the important thing to see is how the date is handled on the Java side, and how it is serialized when sent to the client. I suspect that is the problem. it should be in ISO format, and probably is not.

Comment: I agree with @GreyBeardedGeek. It doesn't seem to an angular issue.

Comment: You're both correct! It was not properly formatted on the Java-side when sent to angular. In the JSON format, I was using 'DD' instead of 'dd'.  `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ")`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was on the Java-side. When propogating the date to the angular app, I was using `DD` instead of `dd` for the JSON formatting. `DD` returns the day of the year, instead of day of the month (dd).

Change made:

`@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ")`

Comment: You most probably don’t uppercase `YYYY` either. Please check the difference between lowercase `yyyy` and uppercase `YYYY`.

Comment: You are correct. My solution slipped through the cracks on this issue. Likely due to this reason from the java.text.SimpleDateFormat javadoc: "If week year 'Y' is specified and the calendar doesn't support any week years, the calendar year ('y') is used instead."